# The dark one appearance

Tags: once-upon-a-time

When Rumpelstiltskin an Nimue became "the dark one," they both changed their look - specifically their skin. They had a greenish skin tone so that they resembled more of a "crocodile."

But when Emma and Killian became the dark one(s), they didn't change their look the same way as Rumpelstiltskin an Nimue did. The most noticeable change was Emma's hair color.

Why was that?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I thought they didn't change immediately. It could be that the "crocodile" look is something that develops over time as the evil nature of being the Dark One takes over. Emma and Killian may not have been Dark Ones long enough yet.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If I'm not mistaken, Rumpelstiltskin changed almost immediately. I'm talking about the episode where he killed the previous dark one

Comment: Because the show is on a budget. They could give Nimue amazing makeup, but when it came to Emma, they had to settle for a look that made her seem like a gothic teenager rather than an actual evil person.